# Displaying composite raster in colors other than RGB in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, rgb

I have a composite raster file with three bands in ArcMap 10.1. I am trying to display them in colors different than standard RGB. For example, I want band one to be blue, band two be brown and band three be green.

How can I do this task?

Comment: Please give more details about how that Brown band would behave.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap 10.3 and above you would be able to make a color map (.clr) file which would allow you to create custom definitions to be applied to your raster.

For your version of ArcMap, try the following:

In the table of contents, right-click the raster layer that you want to draw showing unique values, and click Properties.

- Click the Symbology tab.
- Click the Color scheme drop-down arrow and click a color scheme.
- Open the Properties to modify specifics about how the color scheme is generated.
- Save the color scheme

Additional resources

- [Drawing a multiband raster dataset as an RGB composite](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000073000000)
- [Drawing thematic raster datasets representing unique categories](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/representing_unique_categories_such_as_land_use/009t00000074000000/)